# Get all categories and subcategories with api prestashop

Tags: php, api, prestashop

i have a little problem with the Prestashop WebService.
Could ypu helpme ?
I'd like get all categories and subcategories of my shop with prestashop API.
I 've followed instruction and read documentation an examples, but i'm confused about use of "children()" and "attributes()".

This is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_error', 1); 

define('DEBUG', false);                                         // Debug mode
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://localhost/myshop');                          // Root path of your PrestaShop store
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', '*********************************');  // Auth key (Get it in your Back Office)
require_once('api/PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

// Here we make the WebService Call
try
{
        $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
        // Here we set the option array for the Webservice : we want customers resources
        $opt['resource'] = 'categories';
        // We set an id if we want to retrieve infos from a customer
        if (isset($_GET['id']))
                $opt['id'] = (int)$_GET['id']; // cast string => int for security measures

        // Call
        $xml = $webService->get($opt);

        // Here we get the elements from children of customer markup which is children of prestashop root markup
        $resources = $xml->children()->children();
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)
{
        // Here we are dealing with errors
        $trace = $e->getTrace();
        if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
        else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
        else echo 'Other error';
}




?>
```

and then ?
How can i retrieve name and id of category ?
And how can i retrieve name, id and taxonomy of subcategories ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

At this stage, Prestashop returns a collection of Category URLs. 
Then you have to call again Prestashop API on every single URL to get the actual category data with

```
$resources->id ; $resources->name->language[0][0];
```

Your internet browser is your friend. Try any command first with your browser to see what you get. 
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check the rendering options in http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+8+-+Advanced+Use#Chapter8-AdvancedUse-RenderingOptions

You might have to use display option as well in $opt to get name or any other param apart from id...